# algorithmicx: how to redefine end if in the right way

Tags: algorithmicx

I'm from Russia and there we have different form of "end if" than just "\algorithmicend \algorithmicif" (*кесли* at least in my university)

But when I'm trying to redefine that according to official documentation in that way:

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\textbf{\underline{кесли}}}
```

it fails:

```
  ERROR: LaTeX Error: \algorithmicendif undefined.
```

Has the command changed since the last edition of the official documentation?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `algpseudocode` package doesn't define any `\alrgorithmicendif` macro. The "endif" keyword is instead define in the last argument of `\algdef{SE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}`. You can copy and past that line of code in your preamble (after load `algpseudocode`) customize it to your taste.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jubobs in the comments you should redefine the If block (see also algorithmicx package documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\textbf{\underline{кесли}}}
\algblockdefx[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}{\algorithmicendif}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \If{$a = b$}
            \State \Comment $a = b$
        \EndIf
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```